# Order of ggplot2 stat_function legend labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Changing the order of legend labels for ggplot2 when it involves specifying the levels of a factor, as in [this example](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/ggplot2-changing-the-default-order-of-legend-labels-and-stacking-of-data/):

```
diamonds$cut <- factor(diamonds$cut, levels = rev(levels(diamonds$cut)))
```

I am trying to change the order of legend labels for `stat_function` layers in this plot generated with the following code:

[image: stat function plot]

```
myfun1 <- function(x) -.167*x + 0.032*x^2 -0.002*x^3 + .694 # low
myfun2 <- function(x) -.167*x + 0.032*x^2 -0.002*x^3 + .694 + 0.249 # mid vs. low
myfun3 <- function(x) -.167*x + 0.032*x^2 -0.002*x^3 + .694 + 0.492 # high vs. low

df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 8), y = c(0, 8)) # make highest first

myplot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + # maybe need to change x-axis labels
  stat_function(fun = myfun1, aes(color = "Lowest")) +
  stat_function(fun = myfun2, aes(color = "Average")) +
  stat_function(fun = myfun3, aes(color = "Highest")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 8)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ylab("Proportion of Videos Watched") +
  xlab("") +
  scale_colour_brewer("Students' Course Grade", type = "qual", palette = 4, direction = -1) +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        legend.direction = "vertical") +
  theme(text=element_text(size = 16, family= "Times")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:8,
                     labels = paste0("Wave ", 1:9)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

myplot
```

How could I change the order of these `stat_function` legend labels so they are ordered `Lowest`, `Average`, `Highest`?

Comment: (1) Calculate the new variables before plotting, put them in the data frame, melt and set factor levels, (2) Maybe prepend color labels with digits, e.g. `1 Lowest`, `2 Average`, etc.

Comment: Just add `limits = c("Highest", "Average", "Lowest")` to `scale_colour_brewer()`.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns this work